# How to select the beginning of the following April in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Could you please help me select a date which is the beginning of a particular following month, e.g. April?
For example, if it is Jan 08 2013, it should select April 01 2013, but if it is June 08 2013, it should select April 01 2014.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `DATEADD` and the `DATEPART` function, like this short example:

```
DECLARE @Date Datetime

SET @Date = '2013.01.08 00:00:00'

SELECT DATEADD(year, 
CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, @Date) < 4 
THEN 0 
ELSE 1 END, 
  DATEADD(day, -DATEPART(day, @Date) + 1, 
     DATEADD(month, -DATEPART(month, @Date) + 4, @Date)))
```

Comment: I like this, accept it always gives me April of the year of @Date rather than the following April, as I specified in my question...

Comment: I changed it, now it should work well, I forget to add + 0 or + 1 to the year

Comment: Same problem as mentioned above

Comment: Please try it again, for 2013.01.08 it gives me 2013.04.01 for 2013.07.08 it gives me 2014.04.01.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a [calendar table](http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html), then you can simply do something like this:

```
select 
    min([Date])
from 
    dbo.Calendar
where
    MonthNumber = 4 and
    DayNumber = 1 and
    [Date] > getdate()
```

Querying a calendar table is usually clearer, simpler and more flexible than using date functions. You might also want to consider what happens if today is April 1: do you want today's date, or next year's?

If you're interested in April 1 because it's the start of a financial year, you can add that information to your calendar table directly:

```
select 
    min([Date])
from 
    dbo.Calendar
where
    IsStartOfFinancialYear = 0x1 and
    [Date] > getdate()
```

Comment: Thanks, I just prefer not to maintain an additional table so far, but I appreciate it.

Comment: @DavidShochet Personally I would prefer to maintain data in a table rather than cryptic code; your discussion in response to Andras's solution shows nicely the potential problems with writing and maintaining date logic using functions. However in the end you know best what is most suitable for your own environment.